# How do I get the specific part of a URL using jQuery and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am checking out an order in WordPress via jQuery AJAX. Upon successfully posting, WordPress returns a response to me with a result `success` value and `url` value.

I want to get the particular part of this `url` so I can use the `id` as an object for my purpose.

This is the structure of the url: 
http://localhost/mywebsite/checkout/order-received/28564?key=wc_order_5b4dbc6b2f459

This is my current code:

```
j('.my-checkout').on('submit', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  var billing_customer_type = j("#billing_customer_type").val();
  // and so on...

  j.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/mywebsite/ajax=checkout',
    cache: false,
    data: {
      'billing_customer_type': billing_customer_type,
      // and so on..
    },
    success: function(result) {
      var orderResponseUrl = result.redirect;

      j('.order-response-url').html(orderResponseUrl);
      // http://localhost/mywebsite/checkout/order-received/28564?key=wc_order_5b4dbc6b2f459

      orderResponseUrl.split("/");
      console.log(orderResponseUrl[3]);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(error);
    },
    complete: function() {}
  });
});
```

The result of my code above is just the the letter "p". I think because it started of the first letter of `http` and I used the index `[3]`.

Do you know how can I get the specific part of the `url` that is `28564`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the URL that you need to interact with is always the same, you can split the returned url at the 'order-received/' portion (which gives an array of everything before that, and everything after it).

Then rather than splitting again on the '?" which is another way of doing it - you can use `parseFloat()` to get the order number. This works since parseFloat returns all numerical values up to but not including the first non-numerical character ("?").

```js
var urlStr = 'http://localhost/mywebsite/checkout/order-received/28564?key=wc_order_5b4dbc6b2f459';

var orderNumber = parseFloat(urlStr.split('order-received/')[1]);
console.log(orderNumber); //gives 28564
```

Answer (score 1):

Because when you do `orderResponseUrl.split("/");` it does NOT change `orderResponseUrl`, it creates a new array.

```
var parts = orderResponseUrl.split("/");
console.log(parts);
```

Answer (score 1):

if the length is always same then you can use substring function.

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substring(1, 4);
```

now res contain

```
console.log(res); // ell
```

if you do not know the index, you can find like this.

```
var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.indexOf("welcome");
```

now n look like

```
console.log(n); // 13
```